# How many display ads are there supposed to be on each page?

Tags: support, advertising

It's my understanding that there are at least 2 display ads on each question page, as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). But I have seen question pages with 1 display ad only. Other than the one on top, there is no other display ad in between answers, even if there are more than one (>=2) answers to the question. Is that normal?

Comment: Do you want ... more ads?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Just wonder how?

Comment: possibly related: [Lazy loading our leaderboard ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348103/165773) at MSE

Comment: No idea. Stack Overflow seems to be pretty chill as far as ads go. [At 200 rep you can reduce the amount of ads you see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). I believe they get most of their money from Jobs and Teams these days...

Comment: some people actually prefer ads, as long as they are properly sized and blended in well with other content

Comment: [Zero](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation)

Comment: Regarding Laurel's answer, I would not be surprised if the number of views a question gets affects the number of ads on it. Deleted questions probably don't max out on ads given that only 10K+ users can see them. A question that reliably gets X number of views per month might get the max of 3 ads.

Comment: @Zoe Or just the default Opera installation :)

Answer (score 5):

According to the MSE post [Lazy loading our leaderboard ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348103/323179):

> When working through the different options, we wanted to make sure that there is a maximum of 3 ads (1 job ad and 2 banner ads) in-view in virtually all cases. How many ads you actually see depends on several factors **including whether or not we have sold ads for the particular page**.

Comment: They can't be selling ads for each question page, can they?

Comment: @BellmanEqn probably not each individual question but maybe by tag. Also it sounds like there are more factors than just this that come into play.

Answer (score 4):

The amount of ads you see depends on numerous of factors, including the number of answers the question has, the number of ads you've seen, the rep you have, etc.. [As Laurel noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397624/11957819) we're keeping a [limit of maximum 3 ads (1 job ad and 2 banner ads) in-view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348103/323179) in virtually all cases. But usually, you'd see less than that.

Comment: What does "in-view" mean? Is that 1 job ad the one on the right?

Comment: @BellmanEqn 'm referring that it would be in the viewport of your browser. The job ad is indeed the ad on the right with the different job listings.